# how to replace old all documents with new documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a json data list of 50000 document in my collection.

```json
{
  domainName: "abc.com",
  link: "https://example.com",
  price: "$33"
},
{
  domainName: "sdf.com",
  link: "https://example.com",
  price: "$33"
}
```

I am inserting like this

```
collection.insertMany(data)
```

data is the array of 50000 list

I want to create a collection and insert it to the database. Now I have to insert new json data and want to remove the old data(500000) with updated data in the same collection.
each time I am inserting new documents with

```
collection.insertMany(data)
```

the new documents merged with old one and documents counts increased to 100000.
I just want to replace all documents with new documents

How can I do that in a single command?

Comment: You can delete the collection and create a new one with same name.

Comment: I want to do it in a single command. like deleting and inserting documents OR just replacing all documents. How can I do that?

Comment: Use bulkWrite for ease of use in single query. check the answer I have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bulkWrite` option in mongodb

try this,

```
let ops = [];
    ops.push({ deleteMany: { "filter": {} } },)
    let data = [{
        domainName: 'abc.com',
        link: 'https://example.com',
        price: '$33'
    },
    {
        domainName: 'sdf.com',
        link: 'https://example.com',
        price: '$33'
    }]
    data.forEach(element => {
        ops.push({ insertOne: { "document": element } },)
    });

    let x = await db1.bulkWrite(
        ops,
        { ordered: true }
    );
```

keep `ordered:true`, for maintaining the order of execution. otherwise `deleteMany` can possibly executed at the end. This will `delete all` documents in the collection and the `insert` all.
You can use `updateMany` operation also
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/
You can use

```
  db.collection.bulkWrite(
       [
          { insertOne : <document> },
          { updateOne : <document> },
          { updateMany : <document> },
          { replaceOne : <document> },
          { deleteOne : <document> },
          { deleteMany : <document> }
       ],
       { ordered : false }
    )
```

above operations in `bulkWrite`.

Comment: This works as data is an array. But my data is a JSON object sized 500mb+. And I am uploading it through JSONStream. How can I do that ? thanks

Comment: When I am using insertMany, showing insertMany is deprecated. 
`(node:19606) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: bulk operation `insertMany` has been deprecated; use multiple `insertOne` ops instead`